# How can I trigger a Lambda function to act multiple video files in an S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, triggers

I am working on a Lambda function that will trigger when a folder of video files is placed inside of an S3 bucket.

The Lambda would then iterate through the video files in order to create the URI list in order to stitch them all together using MediaConvert.

Presently, my Lambda is triggering on each video separately.  Would I have to save them all to an SQS?  I am trying to avoid making it too complicated

Comment: But how would you know which video file is the last one?

Comment: Great question.  I would have to somehow have to put a time limit on it, or if they are all within the same folder?

Comment: You have to figure out this with the producer/uploader of the files. You can have times, special naming conventions for a files from the same group, with last file called `_END`, or fix number of files in each group, ...

Comment: Interesting.  These files come from a video camera so they have a random number of files.  You have given me some ideas of ways to at least store them and then recall them back.  It could be a simple timeout since I would only be running these intermittently and not back to back.

Comment: You would need to code such logic into your Lambda function. It would be triggered by _every_ upload and could then check if the last file was uploaded. If so, it should process the files. However, this doesn't make it easy to process them after a "simple timeout" since the Lambda function will not be triggered after a period of time -- it is only triggered when objects _are_ created. You'd need some way of 'checking back' after a period of time.